How to flatten this JSON file in ADF?
I'm working on a project in Azure Data Factory (ADF) where I need to flatten JSON data from the Cost Management API. I receive the data in JSON format via a copy data activity, and it looks like this:
{
  "id": "id1",
  "name": "name1",
  "type": "Microsoft.CostManagement/query",
  "location": null,
  "sku": null,
  "eTag": null,
  "properties": {
    "nextLink": "https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/billingid1",
    "columns": [
      { "name": "Cost", "type": "Number" },
      { "name": "UsageDate", "type": "Number" },
      { "name": "ResourceId", "type": "String" },
      { "name": "ServiceName", "type": "String" },
      { "name": "Currency", "type": "String" }
    ],
    "rows": [
      [1, 20241101, "subscription1", "Microsoft Defender for Cloud", "EUR"],
      [2, 20241101, "subscription2", "Microsoft Defender for Cloud", "EUR"]
    ]
  }
}

I'm only interested in the values in the rows array, and I want each sub-array to be stored as a separate row in a CSV or Parquet file, with each item in the sub-array assigned its own column. My expected output would look like this:



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5




1
20241101
subscription1
Microsoft Defender for Cloud
EUR


2
20241101
subscription2
Microsoft Defender for Cloud
EUR



Question:
How can I transform this JSON structure in ADF to achieve this format? I'm unable to use Data Flow in ADF, so any guidance on flattening the data using other ADF components would be greatly appreciated.

I tried using the 'Mapping' option in the copy data activity with collection references, but I haven't been able to get the correct result.
I also attempted to pass the output of the web call to a filter activity, reducing the JSON to only include the rows with @activity('web1').output.properties.rows. This successfully returns a format that seems suitable for using the mapping functionality, but I'm unable to set this output as the source in my copy data activity.

This question is similar to: What are ways to convert JSON to CSV locally without any third party tools. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have to use dataflow to get your requirement, otherwise you should use pyspark to transform the json in databricks and read the notebook in ADF.

Aside from this possibly being a duplicate, this is off-topic as written, as you only provided a set of requirements, without any specific work of your own (aside from mentioning one thing you tried). It's important to provide a [mcve] with all relevant details.

You have to use dataflow to achieve your requirement, you can't create new columns using ADF components, you should use flatten transformation and derived column transformations to achieve your requirement as follows:
Read your Api as source of dataflow, add flatten transformation to the source and configure it as below:

You will get the output as below:

Add derived column transformation to the flatten transformation to create columns as follows:

Derived column output:

Add select transformation to select required columns, you will get your requirement as shown below:

Add sink as required to the select transformation and debug the pipeline with dataflow activity. If you unable to use data flow, alternatively you can try with Py spark code in databricks if you have access as follows:
Call you Api in databricks or store your Json in storage account, mount it using below code:
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<accessKey>"  
  }
) 

Load the JSON data from Azure Blob Storage and Extract and flatten rows array using below code:
json_path = "/mnt/files/sample.json"
data_df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(json_path)
rows_df = data_df.select(explode(col("properties.rows")).alias("row"))

Split each row into individual columns using below code:
result_df = rows_df.select(
    col("row")[0].alias("Column1"),
    col("row")[1].alias("Column2"),
    col("row")[2].alias("Column3"),
    col("row")[3].alias("Column4"),
    col("row")[4].alias("Column5")
)

you will get the result_df as you required as shown below:

Save the flattened data to CSV or Parquet format in your desired storage location using below code:
result_df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv/.parquet(<output_path>)

Here is the complete code for your reference:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

json_path = "/mnt/files/sample.json"
data_df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(json_path)
rows_df = data_df.select(explode(col("properties.rows")).alias("row"))
result_df = rows_df.select(
    col("row")[0].alias("Column1"),
    col("row")[1].alias("Column2"),
    col("row")[2].alias("Column3"),
    col("row")[3].alias("Column4"),
    col("row")[4].alias("Column5")
)
result_df.show()


FYI the OP showed no work at all, just a set of requirements based on some input data. What you provided doesn't actually answer any specific question; rather, it is a custom solution of your own. And this is not what Stack Overflow is for.
